# How to hide certain options in drop down menu in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am preparing a booking system for sports facilities. In the booking page, I have created a calendar, and I have some complications. For example, if the user selects Saturday, I want only a certain number of options to appear. How can I do it? This is my code so far

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
altField: "#alternate",
altFormat: "DD"
});
});`
</script>

<form action="booking.php" method="post">
<tr><td>Sports Facility:</td><td><select name = "sports_facility">
    <option name="sport1" value = "Basketball">Basketball</option>
<option name="sport6" value = "Tennis">Tennis Court (Multistorey Carpark)</option></td></tr>

</select>

</table>
<tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datePicker" />&nbsp; Day:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" name="vAlternate" size="8" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Time:</td><td><select>
  <option value="Time 1">9.00am-11.00am</option>
  <option value="Time 2">11.00am-1.00pm</option>
  <option value="Time 3">1.00pm-3.00pm</option>
<option value="Time 7">9.00pm-11.00pm</option> </select>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to do it without reloading the page, you need to use JavaScript to alter the options instead of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your "select" and "options" an ID. Like so:

```
<select id="time">
    <option id="option_1" value="Time 1">9.00am-11.00am</option>
    <option id="option_2" value="Time 2">11.00am-1.00pm</option>
    <option id="option_3" value="Time 3">1.00pm-3.00pm</option>
</select>
```

After that, you can add JS filters.

```
$(function(){
    var filters = [];
    filters['Sunday'] = [1,3];
    filters['Monday'] = [1,2];
    //Etc...
}
```

Then, when you want to apply these filters, you can do something like this:

```
function displayOptionsByDay(day){
    $('#time option').css('display', 'none').wrap('<span style="display: none;"/>');
    for(var i = 0; i < filters[day].length; i++){
        $('#option_' + filters[day][i]).css('display', 'inline').unwrap();
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7pasc/)'s the fiddle